# Append a result to a list in R and sapply question

Tags: r, function, sapply, montecarlo

New to R, want to write a monte carlo function that takes 3 arguments as input:

```
price: stock prices vector over a time period
strike: strike price 
knock : knockout price
```

Here is my code:

```
payoff.arr <- list()
option_payoff <- function(hsp, strike, knock){
  for (p in hsp){
    if (p <knock){
      payoff <- max(p-strike, 0)
    }
    else{
      payoff <- 0
    }
    payoff.arr<-append(payoff)
  }
}
```

However when I call the function: `option_payoff(price,105,130)` (price is a vector),
it shows: `Error in append(payoff) : argument "values" is missing, with no default`
What am I doing wrong? And for functions that takes more than 1 arguments how do I use sapply or lapply? I try to use sapply and it shows : `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "knock" is missing, with no default`

Comment: `append` requires at least two arguments - the first is the list to append to, the second is the values to append. I think you want `payoff.arr <- append(payoff.arr, payoff)`.

Comment: You can also initialize `payoff <- 0` before the `if` statement and get rid of the `else`.  I don't know what your parameter objects are, but `for` loops can usually be replaced in vectorized R with a member of the `apply` functions

Answer (score 1):

You should specify something to append !

for example

```
> append(1:3,666)
[1]   1   2   3 666
```

appends `666` to `1,2,3`.

As mentioned in the comments, you'd probably want `payoff.arr <- append(payoff.arr, payoff)`